# Shiny server download timeout 60s

Tags: shiny, server, shinyapps

I deployed a shiny app in a ubuntu server.
I have a download button to save several plots at the same time.
Is taking more than 60s to create and download the pdf document. By default, the shiny server have a 60s timeout and that is why is not working. I've been trying to bypass that setting but so far I haven't been successful.
I added this to the server config but its not working.

http_keepalive_timeout 3000;
app_idle_timeout 380;

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Try to set the "Initial Timeout" to 3600 in the Runtime.

Comment: Just tried it and it didnt work =(

Comment: I have posted a picture (below) of what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

When it fails due to 60 seconds timeout try to change the "Initial Timeout" to 3600 or even 7200, depending on how long your program will need to deploy.

[image]

Comment: I tried that in the server configuration file. I added app_init_timeout 3600; but didnt work either.